# Why not all NSLayoutconstraints changing with animation, and how to fix it?

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I have two subViews in ViewController that located one after another (bottom of first connected to the top of second)

First view is changing its height animated (example below), so I expected that second view will descend with animation too, but its not..

How to make it all animated?

Animation block for first view

```
func animate(){
    layoutIfNeeded()
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1){
        self.labelHeight.constant = 70 // this is constraint
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constraints between sibling views are added to their shared super view so you should call `layoutIfNeeded()` on it. For example:

```
func animate(){
    self.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1){
        self.labelHeight.constant = 70 // this is constraint
        self.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, and  genius! Thank)